# Why does my microSD card have a second row of contacts?

Tags: micro-sd-card

I bought a Lexar microSDXC card for my GoPro. It has a second row of contacts that other microSD cards don't have. The card came with a USB reader that uses those extra contacts, but it also works fine in other readers and devices like the GoPro.

What are the benefits of this extra row of contacts?

[image: Lexar card on the right]

Answer (score 158, accepted):

This is a feature of newer cards called the "Ultra High Speed Bus."

It allows the card to transfer data faster.

USB 3.0 is like this too - it has additional pins which allow faster data transfer, but is still backward compatible with things that do not have the additional pins (will fall back to slower speed).

From [Secure Digital Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Ultra_High_Speed_.28UHS.29_bus):

> UHS-II
>
> Specified in version 4.0, further raises the data transfer rate to a
>   theoretical maximum of 156 MB/s (full duplex) or 312 MB/s (half
>   duplex) using an additional row of pins] (a total of 17 pins for
>   full-size and 16 pins for micro-size cards).

Without these extra pins you can only do UHS-I which maxes out at 104 MB/s.

Nice chart on the page comparing all the speeds as well:

```
Bus interface   Logos          Bus speed                    Spec version    
--------------  -------------  ---------------------------  ------------

Default Speed   SD SDHC SDXC   12.5 MByte/s                 1.01

High Speed                     25 MByte/s                   2.00

UHS-I           SDHC SDXC I    12.5 MByte/s (SDR12)         3.01
                               25 MByte/s (SDR25)
                               50 MByte/s (SDR50, DDR50)
                               104 MByte/s (SDR104)          

UHS-II          SDHC SDXC II   156 MByte/s (FD156)          4.00/4.10
                               312 MByte/s (HD312)         

UHS-III         SDHC SDXC III  312 MByte/s (FD312)          6.0
                               624 MByte/s (FD624)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why they skipped spec v5.0?

Comment: @Alex 5.0 wasn't skipped, it added the Video Speed Class ratings in 2016.